# Is it safe to simply rename a .jfif file to .jpg?

Tags: jpeg, image-conversion

I downloaded several images that are are .jfif files. I have various enhancements (e.g. context menus) and processing scripts that are keyed to *.jpg files and would like to use these with the new files.

I have read [Are all JPEG files JFIF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427623/are-all-jpeg-files-jfif), but want to explicitly clarify: is it safe (by which I mean no risk of corruption or errors reading the file, either image data or metadata) to directly rename a .jfif file as a .jpg file?

I am trying to understand whether it's fine to simply rename the files and change the extension directly (i.e. the underlying file format is the same) or whether I need to re-encode/re-save these .jfif files as .jpg files (which might result in some lossy compression / quality loss), because the two file formats are different somehow.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Yes.

JPEG is not a file format - it's a compression method. It doesn't specify how the compressed data should be stored in a file. There are two file formats that fill in this gap: the original JFIF, and the newer Exif<sup>1</sup>. They are very similar, mostly compatible and can even be mixed in a single file. Both use the `.jpg` extension.

Your `.jfif` file is a JPEG-compressed image stored in a JFIF file format. It's a valid content for a `.jpg` file.

---

<sup>1</sup> Technically, TIFF also supports JPEG data, but I don't think I've ever seen such file and it's certainly not a common choice for saving JPEGs.

Comment: Thanks @gronostaj -- I just wanted to check with you about JFIF/EXIF as from the research I did myself, I read that [JFIF is mutually **incompatible** with the newer Exchangeable image file format, EXIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format) (which JPEG uses, right?) - 
 Does your answer contradict that then?... To be clear, am not trying to say you are wrong as I freely admit my knowledge of image standards / file-formats is very limited so I may have-misunderstood, am just trying to do a sanity check / correlate the info together in my head. 

Comment: @Martin [Here you go](https://superuser.com/q/1657522/194694).